# Giving a prefix on import to all classes of a given package in Scala

Tags: scala, import

A common pattern (problem) I see when working in large systems is that of class name collisions. Especially when dealing with different bounded contexts, one can find several classes with the same name in different packages.

I've seen that it is possible in Scala to locally rename the name of a class, but I was wondering if it was at all possible to rename the names of all the imported classes coming from a given package. What I'm looking for is something akin to

```
import data.{*-> Data*} // all classes on data.* will appear with a Data prefix
import domain.{*->Domain*} // all classes on domain.P will appear with a Domain prefix
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not generally possible.

If you were finding yourself wanting to do this in class after class, though, you could go through the pain just once with something like:

```
object Mutables {
    import scala.collection.mutable._
    type MMap[K,V] = Map[K,V]
    type MHashMap[K,V] = HashMap[K,V]
    type MSet[A] = Set[A]
    type MHashSet[A] = HashSet[A]
    // etc.
}
```

then import wherever required:

```
import Mutables._
```

Comment: Ah, that seems like a nice compromise. Thanks